# Sending complex form data via Fetch API to PHP endpoint

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

How can I send a Form like this using Fetch API to a laravel endpoint: The problem I have is that I can't get the file and inputs with the array name "[]" at the same time. I tried to loop through each element of the form and create a json object but when there is a file input in the form it makes it fail because you must send the data as `application/json` format which you have to `JSON.stringyfy(data)` which causes the file input to disapear.

I also tried using `FormData()` which is working perfectly fine with files and other normal inputs but when it comes to the inputs with array name `name[]` or event `price[10]` or `price[1][], It doesnt work. What is the best approach to send this kind of form?

```
<form action="/end-point">

    <input type="text" name="title" value="my article title">
    <textarea name="body" id="" cols="30" rows="10">THis is the body</textarea>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="2">
    
    <input type="radio" name="option[]" value="3">
    <input type="radio" name="option[]" value="4">
    
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="test1">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="test2">

    <select name="service_id[]">
        <option value="1">Service1</option>
        <option value="2">Service2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="service_id[]">
        <option value="1">Service1</option>
        <option value="2">Service2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="service_id[]">
        <option value="1">Service1</option>
        <option value="2">Service2</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="file" name="picture">
    
</form>
```

THe Format I need in the laravel endpoint

```
[
"title" => "my article title"
  "body" => "THis is the body"
  "facilities" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "option" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "3"
  ]
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "test1"
    1 => "test2"
  ]
  "service_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "picture" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#244 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "m16.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\wamp64\tmp"
    filename: "php87C8.tmp"
    basename: "php87C8.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php87C8.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php87C8.tmp"
    aTime: 2020-07-02 04:41:33
    mTime: 2020-07-02 04:41:33
    cTime: 2020-07-02 04:41:33
    inode: 3096224744035967
    size: 25467
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php87C8.tmp"
  }
]
```

Comment: To upload a file, you should be sending a `multipart/form-data` request payload.

Comment: Without knowing **exactly** what format your Laravel backend expects, this is very difficult to answer. Please see the linked duplicate for some general information about uploading both files and data

Comment: @Phil The file is not the problem and I can all form data and the file using new FormData() but the problem happens when there are inputs with array name like <input name="price[]" value="1"> <input name="price[] value="2">

Comment: @Phil You should not have closed my question non of the solutions out there are working in my scenario. I have been researching and developing all the possible ways which developers give but non works.

Comment: Put simply, you cannot embed a file upload like that within JSON. The answers in the duplicate should have explained that

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Vue on this to pass the file.

```
<input type="file" @change="onChange" class="mb-5">
```

On my `methods`

```
onChange(e) {
      this.form.image = e.target.files[0]
    }
```

This will return the image name

then in my **POST** ajax request is this method

```
  let form = new FormData()

  form.append('image', this.form.image)
  form.append('name', this.form.name) // [edited]

  fetch([url], {
    method: 'POST',
    Accept: "application/json",
    body: json.stringify(form)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(image => console.log(image))
```

if this doesn't work try to change the Accept Header.

**EDIT:**

You will also pass the `name` or other field in the append.

**EDIT 2**

```
  let form = new FormData()[];

  foreach(form in forms) {
    form.append('image', this.form.image)
    form.append('name', this.form.name)
  }
  
  fetch([url], {
    method: 'POST',
    Accept: "application/json",
    body: json.stringify(form)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(image => console.log(image))
```

Comment: You are sending only a file, and this is problem when we add some inputs with array name to the form like <input name="something[][10]">

Comment: @VeRJiL you can now check the code. I edited it

Comment: thanks but this doesnt apply, because I am trying to get all the inputs as an array not a signle input

Comment: I tried to edit again my answer but I don't think it will work just try another work around if it doesn't do any.